# Adding field in woo BACS payment settings which will be always "order number" and send it via email to customer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i tried to look everywhere for several hours and could not find anything relevant to what i want.
Is there any way to send one more detail in email for new order when BACS was choosen? This detail must have same formatting as rest of the bank details like SWIFT code or account number and would be named "Variabilný symbol" with result of order number.
this is what i have now all bank details set in woocommerce BACS payment settings
https://snipboard.io/ybu0vk.jpg
and i would like to add one more information which would always be the order number with same formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution if anyone would be interested:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bacs_account_fields', 'custom_bacs_account_field', 10, 2);
function custom_bacs_account_field( $account_fields, $order_id ) {
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$account_fields['variable_symbol' ] = array(
'label' => 'NAME FOR THE LABEL GOES HERE',
'value' => $order->get_order_number()
);
return $account_fields;
}
```

i am not author of this code.